Solving PDE's by separation of variables
I'm having some difficulties understanding how to solve PDEs by Separation of variables
.
Here's an example question from my homework:
PDE HW Question:

Generally, I understand how to manipulate the One-Dimensional Wave Equation to separate the $t$ and $x$ derivatives, however, I don't understand where a given $u(x,0) = f(x)$ would come in. Do we use it once we've reached a Fourier series from the One-Dimensional Wave Equation?
i.e.
$$f(x)=\sum bn*\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi L}{x}\right)$$
If so, how do we use $f(x)$ to solve the coefficients?
If not where doesn't it apply? If you could use the hw problem or a similar problem as an example to walk me through that would be much appreciated!
Thanks for your help and edits :)

Do you not have a textbook or lecture notes from your course?

Wave equation : $$ c^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2}\tag 1$$
Now, in the setting (you must know "basis" for vector space)
$$f(x)=\dfrac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos\left(\dfrac{n \pi x}{L}\right)+b_n \sin \left(\dfrac{n \pi x}{L}\right)\tag 2$$
let $$ F(x,t)=\frac{f(x-ct)+f(x+ct)}{2} \tag 3$$ Then $F(x,0)=f(x)$ from $(3)$. 
you can also easily check that in general by substituting $x-ct$ and $x+ct$ instead of $x$ in $(2)$, 
and from $(3)$ again,
$(1)$ automatically followed.
Now, for example, if you want to get $b_n$, multiply $ \sin \left(\dfrac{n \pi x}{L}\right) $ both sides of $(2)$,
then you can integrate both sides but especially the right side have somewhat
vanishing terms except one term by using:

orthogonality among the different integers' sin functions or
orthogonality between cos and sin functions
finally, you can get constant of the self-integral with a function
(this is $L/2$)


$a_n=(2/L)\int_0^{L} f(x)\cos(n\pi x/L)dx, b_n=(2/L)\int_0^{L} f(x)\sin(n\pi x/L)dx, a_0=(2/L)\int_0^{L}f(x)dx$
